# How can I fix "Type org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer is defined multiple times" error when building an Android APK?

Tags: android, react-native, apk, gstreamer, dex

I have been working on a project for a couple of months integrating gstreamer to a basic react-native Android app. The starting point was [react-native-gstreamer](https://github.com/Kalyzee/react-native-gstreamer) but with a number of modifications to the gstreamer pipeline etc.

My debug builds (created with `yarn android` or `./gradlew assembleDebug`) have been working reliably, on emulated and real devices, but I can't get a release build / signed APK `./gradlew assembleRelease` to work. The build scan showing the error (created with `./gradlew assembleRelease --scan`, doesn't appear to contain any sensitive information?) is at [scans.gradle.com](https://scans.gradle.com/s/isv6h7fulpldy). The error I am stuck on is

> C:\Temp\MyApp\app\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\org\freedesktop\gstreamer\GStreamer.dex: D8: Type org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer is defined multiple times: C:\Temp\MyApp\app\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\org\freedesktop\gstreamer\GStreamer.dex, C:\Temp\MyApp\react-native-gstreamer.transforms\b22258b54d8d354026f3fb18b0251db4\transformed\classes\classes.dex
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

I'm new to Android development (experienced C++/Python mainly), so I could be missing something obvious, this seems to be a common issue (see below) but the link in the error doesn't help me and the solutions I have found have not worked.

The most likely cause that I can't pin down is [some sort of dependency clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49120122/im-getting-an-error-when-building-my-apk), similar to [this issue also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61022373/type-com-google-gson-exclusionstrategy-is-defined-multiple-times), but I don't have lots of dependencies, it seems specifically related to gstreamer, and I don't know where to dig further to find the clash.

`./gradlew app:dependencies` doesn't show any obviously bad dependencies. react-native-gstreamer has a dependency on `com.facebook.react:react-native:+ -> 0.63.4 (*)` and doesn't appear in any other context in the dependencies (i.e. the above dependency appears a few times in the output, but react-native-gstreamer isn't a dependency of other packages and doesn't have other dependencies and there are no other occurrences of gstreamer)

Similar errors elsewhere on stackoverflow and solutions which I have unsuccessfully tested:

- [Delete gradle folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64871677/getting-error-on-generating-signed-apk-type-com-google-gson-exclusionstrategy) - fault still occurs
- [Enable multiDex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323484/multiple-dex-files-define-error-when-building-apk-in-android-studio) in build.gradle - fault still occurs (note minSdkVersion is set to 21, so some messages suggest this should not be necessary, but tried anyway)
- [Similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257959/type-org-json-jsonexception-is-defined-multiple-times) but I am not aware of any dependency
- [./gradlew clean and ./gradlew assembleRelease](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64842452/type-androidx-activity-rdrawable-is-defined-multiple-times) - fault still occurs
- [Various solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497099/type-androidx-appcompat-resources-rdimen-is-defined-multiple-times/60784432#60784432)

  - look at the path given in AS, it should point to \app\build\intermediates\project_dex_archive\debug\out. Go to this path, delete all the *.jar files, leaving the most recent one - fault still occurs (removed file is recreated on next build)
  - Delete the build directory (C:/Temp/MyApp above) - fault still occurs
- [Multidex changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487986/an-error-pops-up-when-building-an-apk) - it looks like this is now outdated for minSdkVersion >= 21, no upvotes and one comment that it didn't fix the original poster's problem, not tested.

Comment: `C:\Temp\MyApp\app\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\org\freedesktop\gstreamer\GStreamer.dex` - the `project_dex_archive` folder generally contains output artifacts which were built from project source files. Is it possible that your `app` module contains `GStreamer.java` source file? If yes - then it might be the root cause of the conflict, since you're most likely have similar artifact which comes from a third party dependency (`react-native-gstreamer.transforms\b22258b54d8d354026f3fb18b0251db4\transformed\classes\classes.dex`).

Comment: The instructions I followed for linking included copying GStreamer.java into the react-native-gstreamer folder so thanks @AlexLipov you're exactly right I have a copy of it in my project, would that be different between debug and release builds? Should I just be able to delete the copied across GStreamer.java file? Or reference the one in the binary Android build? Or delete the supplied ones in the Android build?

Comment: I would expect `debug` builds to fail on this as well, perhaps the `release` variant performs stricter validations. I'm not familiar with this library and with a way you're expected to integrate it in your project - but you should definitely have the class either in your source files or in your dependencies, not both.

Comment: Found the duplicate, I had followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45044210/gstreamer-examples-in-android-studio/46223465#46223465 and copied GStreamer.java manually to the top level, which was clashing with the automatically sed'ed version from the gstreamer Android build makefile. @AlexLipov if you would like to post the above as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message mentions two dex sources which contain the `org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer` class:

- C:\Temp\MyApp\app\intermediates\project_dex_archive\release\out\org\freedesktop\gstreamer\GStreamer.dex
- C:\Temp\MyApp\react-native-gstreamer.transforms\b22258b54d8d354026f3fb18b0251db4\transformed\classes\classes.dex

First source's `project_dex_archive` folder generally contains output artifacts which were built from project source files. Is it possible that your app module contains `GStreamer.java` source file?
If yes - then it might be the root cause of the conflict, since you're most likely have similar artifact packaged in a third party dependency (the second dex source: `react-native-gstreamer`).